# Separating the Edit and Delete Functions In a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that has the Edit and the Delete functionality enabled.

I was wondering if there was a way to separate the two functionalities into two columns. For example having the Edit on the left side of the GridView and the Delete on the Right.

Thanks

Paddy

Comment: How is this funcitonality implemented?

Comment: You can manually design columns.

Comment: @AliRashidi Perfect! Got it, sorry about that. THANKS